# IE conditional comments are not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I have **style_desktop.css** for all the desktop and another **style_mobile.css** for mobile device.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width:781px)" type="text/css"
      href="style_desktop.css"/>
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 780px) and (min-device-width: 320px)"
      href="style_mobile.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

The above code works fine except IE 8 and below. I suppose it is because IE 8 and below does not recognize **"(min-device-width:781px)"**

So I updated the code as below but it is still not working.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width:781px)" type="text/css"
      href="style_desktop.css"/>
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 780px) and (min-device-width: 320px)"
      href="style_mobile.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_desktop.css"/>
 <![endif]-->
```

If it is any **desktop** browser than I want **style_desktop.css** to be linked.
If it is any **mobile** browser than I want **style_mobile.css** to be linked.

By testing I found that the conditional comments are not working.

**Edit:**
I am using wordpress if it makes any difference. I have removed the **get_template_directory_uri();**  from the **href** just for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to enabling HTML5 and CSS3 for older IE:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This helped. I was testing it in IE's compatibility mode. It was not showing it there but was working in actual. Checked on http://www.browserstack.com/